# What are the values of $a$ and $b$?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, radicals

I got this question from our quiz wrong I wonder how my teacher got the correct answers shown. I tried solving the first question but didn't get the right answers. I know the formula for the surface of a right circular cone is $S=πr(r+\sqrt {r^2+h^2})$ but I still followed the given formula for the sake of trying to obtain what my teacher got.

My solution:

Let $x$ be $r$ and $4x$ be $h$. Then,

$$πx\sqrt {x^2+(4x)^2}=8$$
$$πx\sqrt {17x^2}=8$$
$$17π^2x^4=8^2$$
$$x^4=\frac{8^2}{17π^2}$$
$$(x^4)^\frac{1}{4}=(\frac{8^2}{17π^2})^\frac{1}{4}$$
$$x=±\frac{2\sqrt 2}{17^\frac{1}{4}π^\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$x=\frac{2\sqrt 2}{17^\frac{1}{4}π^\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$h=\frac{8\sqrt 2}{17^\frac{1}{4}π^\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$h^2=\frac{128}{17^\frac{1}{2}π}$$
$$a=128$$
$$b=17$$

[image]

Comment: @AmaanM then why on the question it is $(\frac{a\sqrt b}{bπ})$? I wonder...

Comment: Please, use MathJax the next time you ask a question instead of pasting a hand-drawn image

Comment: Your "known" formula $S=\pi r(r+\sqrt {r^2+h^2\;})$ includes the area of a base added to the cone, which doesn't apply here.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso I edited the question.

Comment: @Joffan so what can you say about my solution?

Comment: You didn't quite finish off and write down the values of $a$ and $b$ but apart from that it looks good.

Comment: @Joffan I edited the question. My teacher got different answers. she $a=2$ and $b=8$. I am not sure how she got those.

Comment: No; I don't see any way to get that answer even varying some of the phrasing. Also, technically there's no answer at all, since a distance squared ("the square of its height") can't be represented in inches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math is correct. Given $S = 8$, $h = 4r$, and $h^2 = \frac{a\sqrt{b}}{b\pi}$, we have:

$$ S = \pi r\sqrt{r^2 + h^2} $$

$$ = \pi \frac{\pi h}{4} \sqrt{\frac{1}{16}h^2 + h^2} $$

$$ = \pi \frac{h}{4} \sqrt{\frac{17h^2}{16}} $$

$$ = \frac{\pi h^2 \sqrt{17}}{16} $$

Substituting in $S = 8$, we have

$$ 8 = \frac{\pi h^2 \sqrt{17}}{16} $$

$$ \Rightarrow h^2 = \frac{128}{\sqrt{17}\pi} $$

$$ = \frac{128\sqrt{17}}{17\pi} $$

$$\Rightarrow a = 128, b = 17 $$

Now, if we take the "correct" solution with $a = 2$ and $b = 8$, we still have (from the algebra above):

$$ S = \frac{\pi h^2 \sqrt{17}}{16} $$

Substituting in $a = 2$ and $b = 8$, we have

$$ S = \frac{\pi \sqrt{17}}{16} \frac{2 \sqrt{8}}{8 \pi} $$

$$ = \frac{\sqrt{34}}{32} \neq 8 $$